# C# most simple way to show small overlay similar to windows 11 brightness/volume notifications

Tags: c#, notifications, overlay, toast

Hello fellow community,

I'm working on a small app that helps controlling ASUS gaming laptops using C# Windows Forms Application. I need a most simple way to show a small overlay notification (or toast?) indicating that performance profile has changed by click on a hotkey.

Main use case here - is hotkey will be pressed in **fullscreen game** and this toast should appear over it.

I tried firing a new form with Topmost param, or invoking [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowPos")], it doesn't work.

I have noticed that Windows 11 has very elegant and working solution to indicate brightness / volume changes, and they work in games too.

[Sample screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXenF.png)

Is it any **modern** way to use same notification but for own purposes ? I can't seem to find it in a documentation. Or injecting DirectX is still the only way ?

Thanks!